# Using a Travel Agent for non-Complicated Travel

Tags: air-travel, budget, planning, hotels, travel-agents

I am having issues figuring out the best way to go about booking travel for my honeymoon at the end of August (right in the middle of Labour Day weekend in order to add to the degree of difficultyl). We are planning on leaving from Manitoba and going to a combination of Vancouver and Seattle.

I made initial contact with a local travel agent, and provided her with basic parameters for the trip, including length of stay of budget and kind of a round about of what we wanted to accomplish. She came back and managed to somehow obliterate our budget (which had been set after some research of our own) as well as decrease the length of the trip, which has left a bad taste in my mouth and questioning if I even want to attempt to find another travel agent.

My question would be, for the services I want, which would be essentially be booking hotels and flights, would it be worth it to go with a travel agent? Can they find me significantly better hotels at better prices than I could as a tech savvy individual?

Comment: Why not try the good [kayak.com](http://www.kayak.com) for tickets and [booking](http://booking.com) for hotels? I am sure you will find much cheaper and better offers.

Comment: If you already know how much you would pay, you can start bargaining with the travel agent. Usually they just struggle a little bit more with their computer and find another airline and another hotel for a better price.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no absolute answer to your question but **in general you will get a better price booking yourself**. The lowest price would be to book locally at the last minute but for a honeymoon, people usually want more predictability.

Going for one of the **travel  sites give you the most options which often leads to better prices**. Regardless, try several because properties have different deals at times and not all sites get them or some may be exclusive deals.

Travel agents have their use but it is rarely about money. **When an individual works for you, always expect to pay more.** After all, someone has to get paid. They *may* offer recommendations which *can* lead to savings though based on their knowledge of the area where you are going by suggesting other modifications to your plans which travel sites can rarely do (ex; out-of-town accomodations, other city airports plus transport, etc).

Comment: Last minute is not necessarily the "cheapest" option ...

Comment: The key is *locally at the destination*. If you can get it *locally* before  you get there, even better. There are plenty of small places not listed in travel sites usually. I often book only the first night remotely to have a place to stay and spend the first day shopping for the rest of my trip. There are places and *most importantly* times such as major holidays when this will not work though, so be careful and not during a honeymoon unless you wife love's adventure!